# Call Objects Method from GUI's pushbutton callback in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I use an Object of my GUIHandlingClass to manage my GUI. This object stores the currently open figure and replaces this figure with another figure when I call a method. Basically like this:

```
GUIHandler = GUIHandlingClass('page1.fig');
GUIHandler.ChangePage('page2.fig'); % closes page1.fig, opens page2.fig
delete(GUIHandler); %closes page2.fig
```

Now I want to call ChangePage from within the GUI when I click a button. So far I have tried to set GUIHandler global, so it would be in the scope of the callback (didn't work). Also I have tried to store the GUIHandler in ApplicationData and UserData (didn't work). I am running out of ideas on how to do this. Do you have any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: Please provide a minimal functioning example. See [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I think I cannot provide a minimal functioning example, because it doesn't function.

Comment: I solved it. Global variable worked after all.

Comment: For future questions, minimal NOT functioning example helps as well.